# Is it possible to filter CO2?

Tags: combustion, environmental-chemistry, carbon-dioxide

I'm diving into the world of chemistry here, pondering a concept that might sound a bit out there. Can we actually filter out CO2 from a car's exhaust pipe and store it until it's safe to handle?

This idea is way beyond my beginner chemistry knowledge, but it's interesting, I'm curious: Are there methods in chemistry that could potentially filter and capture CO2 emissions from car exhaust? And if so, could we find a way to store this CO2 until it can be safely dealt with?

I'm also wondering about the challenges this kind of filtration might face. Are there chemical principles or reactions that could help trap CO2 while letting other gases through? And could this ever become a widespread solution for reducing vehicle emissions?

Can't wait for the thoughts, insights, or any existing research on CO2 filtration in car exhausts. Can we turn this idea into a mainstream reality, or is it still it still science fiction?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to sequester CO2 from combustion, it is much more practical to do so at a stationary source such as a coal or gas-burning power plant than it is to do so in a vehicle.

Comment: Will always stay science fiction because of thermodynamics. For power stations where the heat is used for district heating, it might make sense.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible as many things are. All is about scalability and money.

From $\pu{20 L}$ of gasoline/petrol is formed roughly $\pu{44 kg \ce{CO2}}$ and $\pu{18 kg}$ of $\ce{H2O}$. If captured by $\pu{80 kg}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$, it would form $\pu{106 kg \ce{Na2CO3}}$ and in total with the input $\pu{36 kg}$ of $\ce{H2O}$. Accordingly heavy supporting material and construction.

Cars would need quite a huge, heavy and expensive to maintain absorption unit.  It would also lead to big challenge for engine power. And I do not see anybody would buy such a car nor handle so big amount of material.

Comment: Trade off *Pressure needed to push gases through*  versus *efficiency of absorption and related mass and volume*.  // As an extreme example - imagine somebody would put a bunch of old cotton/linen clothes to the tubing of the engine exhaust, so the engine would need significantly higher pressure to blow exhaust gases out. Or that there is inserted some element with many narrow gas passes, again with the pressure drop on it.

Comment: My bad my keyboard is a bit funky, I was think something like [this](https://www.cnet.com/culture/co2ube-filters-out-carbon-dioxide-from-your-tailpipe/) just to clarify!

Comment: It is a fake to pull money from pockets for false good feeling you did something good for environment. It may work, but for very small amount and flow rate of CO2. Not for more than 100 mL of gasoline, probably less. And with its small size, it cannot help itself but to allow to bypass of most of the exhaust gases.

Comment: Oh I see, It is possible, although it would be very exspensive and large is what im getting. I planning on entering this idea into a [Young Entrepreneurs Challenge](https://youngentrepreneurschallenge.com/?playlist=b69133f&video=57b148c) thing, I agree it needs refining, Is there anything possible to make it more efficient/affordable for the average consumer? Its been a decade since the idea was proposed hence I think there could be a space to make it better. Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: Rather, new ideas are seldom new ideas and if they were abandoned, there is good reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compress the exhaust gas, remove all the water it contains, and then compress it further until the CO2 condenses, which you can fill into standard gas bottles. Every litre of fuel turns into roughly three times the amount of liquid CO2.

The fuel consumption of your car additionally increases drastically to run the machinery for separating and liquifying the CO2, even if you could do so with prefect effiency. Spoiler: you can't, meaning the fuel consumption increases even more.

And then you still have those gas bottles which you'll have to pay somebody to empty for you and press the CO2 into an empty oil field or something.

I recommend you just buy yourself a smaller car next time. Or an electric one.